# WPF Richtextbox text selection

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, textselection

I have a WPF richtextbox having a Table as a Flowdocument. I need to copy content of selected table rows using C# on mouse right click.

The problem I m facing is being unable to get selected rows.

Using following function but unable to get selected rows of Richtextbox.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

```
public static List<TableRow> GetSelectedParagraphs(FlowDocument document, TextSelection selection)
    {
        return document.Blocks.OfType<TableRow>().Where(w => selection.Contains(w.ContentStart)).ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`TableRow` instances are inside `RowGroup` instances that are inside `Table` instances. And tables are blocks.

You can try the code below:

```
public static List<TableRow> GetSelectedParagraphs(FlowDocument document, TextSelection selection)
{
    return document.Blocks
        .OfType<Table>()
        .SelectMany(x => x.RowGroups)
        .SelectMany(x => x.Rows)
        .Where(w => selection.Contains(w.ContentStart))
        .ToList();
}
```

## Update: Full example code

### Xaml

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Class="Blend.MainWindow">
    <StackPanel>
        <RichTextBox Name="RichTextBox" SelectionChanged="OnSelectionChanged">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Table CellSpacing="0">
                    <Table.Columns>
                        <TableColumn Width="50" />
                        <TableColumn Width="50" />
                    </Table.Columns>
                    <TableRowGroup>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Run>1</Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Run>2</Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                        <TableRow>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Run>3</Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                            <TableCell BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
                                <Paragraph>
                                    <Run>4</Run>
                                </Paragraph>
                            </TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    </TableRowGroup>
                </Table>
                <Paragraph />
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
        <TextBlock><Run>Rows selected: </Run><Run Name="TableRowCount" /></TextBlock>
        <TextBlock><Run>Selection Text: </Run><Run Name="SelectionText" /></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

### Code Behind

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Documents;

namespace Blend
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TableRowCount.Text = GetSelectedParagraphs(RichTextBox.Document, RichTextBox.Selection).Count.ToString();
            SelectionText.Text = RichTextBox.Selection.Text;
        }

        public static List<TableRow> GetSelectedParagraphs(FlowDocument document, TextSelection selection)
        {
            return document.Blocks
                .OfType<Table>()
                .SelectMany(x => x.RowGroups)
                .SelectMany(x => x.Rows)
                .Where(w => selection.Contains(w.ContentStart))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks filhit,
but another problem is that I am not able to get richtextbox selection.
m Using
TextSelection txtSel = rtxtBox.Selection;

But getting txtSel.Text as empty.

How can I get selected rows of richtextbox table???

Comment: @AshishBathla I've added full example. Does that work for you?